# Function vs Stored Procedure as external name property

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, dll

I am trying to map an existing .dll file into SQL Server and for this I have created an assembly, then I have used `create procedure` syntax with `external` keyword.

Can we achieve the same using creating function script? If not, please let me know when to use function or stored procedure to do the same.

```
create function ConvertToText
    (@Resume varbinary(max))
return varchar(8000)
as external name Conversions.Sqlconversions.ConvertToText


create procedure ConvertToText
    (@Resume  varbinary(max))
as external name Conversions.Sqlconversions.ConvertToText
```

Is it solely dependent on the fact that whether there is return value from the same?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you decorated the methods in your CLR assembly.

You would use `create procedure` when mapping stored procedures, e.g.:

```cs
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]  
  public static int PriceSum(out SqlInt32 value)  
  {
    //...
  }
```

You would use `create function` when mapping user-defined functions, e.g.:

```cs
  //Scalar User-Defined Function
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
  public static int ReturnOrderCount()
  {
    return 1 + 47;
  }

  //Table-Valued User-Defined Function
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
  public static IEnumerable FindInvalidEmails(SqlDateTime modifiedSince)
  {
    return Something_Something_IEnumerable;
  }
```

References:

- [CLR Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/clr-stored-procedures)
- [CLR Scalar-Valued Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions)
- [CLR Table-Valued Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions)